# a python thread is not working

Tags: python, multithreading

My code is here.

```
import time
import thread

def myfunction(sleeptime,lock,*args):
    count = 0
    while 1:
    #entering critical section
        lock.acquire()
        count +=1 
        print count," Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for ",sleeptime
        time.sleep(sleeptime) 
        print count," Now releasing lock "
        lock.release()

if __name__=="__main__":

    lock=thread.allocate_lock()
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,(2,lock))
    #thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,("Thread No:2",2,lock))

    while 1:pass
```

here I try to make a simple thread and counting them but my code show some syntax error which look this.

```
 File "thread_example.py", line 6
    while 1:
           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

but when I remove the count from myfunction(),my code work but what's the wrong in count I don't understand.

***another question:***
as a new in python I try to learn thread.Little more change in above code which looks like this

```
import time
import thread

def myfunction(string,sleeptime,lock,*args):
    while 1:
        lock.acquire() 
        print string," Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for ",sleeptime
        time.sleep(sleeptime) 
        print string," Now releasing lock and then sleeping again"
        lock.release()

if __name__=="__main__":

    lock=thread.allocate_lock()
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,("Thread No:1",2,lock))
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,("Thread No:2",2,lock))

    while 1:pass
```

before running I think that I get **Thread No:1** and **Thread No:2** sequentially but my output is this

```
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:1  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:2  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:2  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:1  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:1  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:2  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:2  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:1  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:1  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
Thread No:1  Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1  Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for  2
```

which is also not understandable for me.So why it get Thread No:1 so many time??

for any suggestion of learning thread in python is also helpful for me.

Comment: Your first problem is because you mixed tabs and spaces. There is a tab before `count = 0`, but only spaces before `while 1:`.

Comment: @Neil I try what you say but it does not work and also asking you that are you sure that the while have one space only and the count have a tab??

Comment: If you click on the `edit` button to review what you posted, there is a tab before `count = 0` and four spaces before `while`. Similarly, if you copy and paste your code into an editor, and explicitly add a tab in front of count, but use spaces elsewhere, you will get the exact error you posted.

Comment: I got my firs solution.Thanks @Neil but what's the problem in second one??

Answer (score 0):

In `myfunction`, the printed message says "releasing lock and then *sleeping again*", but the code doesn't have this second sleep.

Cleaning up both problems:

```
import time
import thread

def myfunction(string,sleeptime,lock,*args):
    count = 0   
    while 1:
        lock.acquire()
        count += 1
        print "{} {} Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for {}".format(string, count, sleeptime)
        time.sleep(sleeptime) 
        print "{} {} Now releasing lock and then sleeping again".format(string, count)
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(sleeptime)

if __name__=="__main__":

    lock=thread.allocate_lock()
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,("Thread No:1",0.5,lock))
    thread.start_new_thread(myfunction,("Thread No:2",0.5,lock))

    while 1:pass
```

The output is:

```
Thread No:1 1 Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for 0.5
Thread No:1 1 Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:2 1 Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for 0.5
Thread No:2 1 Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1 2 Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for 0.5
Thread No:1 2 Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:2 2 Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for 0.5
Thread No:2 2 Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
Thread No:1 3 Now Sleeping after Lock acquired for 0.5
Thread No:1 3 Now releasing lock and then sleeping again
```

Comment: I know that **time.sleep(sleeptime)** works for my code but the question is here why I need to add this??I read the manual of **allocate_lock()** and **acquire()** function.It say "Without the optional argument, this method acquires the lock unconditionally, if necessary waiting until it is released by another thread (only one thread at a time can acquire a lock — that’s their reason for existence)" so without adding **time.sleep(sleeptime)** it should be work i think but it is not.so why it is not and why I have to add sleep() function.